# Program drops from while loop after 9 cycles. Programming in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I have DHT11 temperature sensor connected to my RPi. I am using Adafruit DHT driver and want to edit Adafruit_DHT.c to keep on running until user manually will stop program. I am new to C and I can't find the reason why program exits after 9times performed in commander(linux). All I try is to use while in main function. Thank you for you help.

```
#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE        0x20000000
#define GPIO_BASE                (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000) /* GPIO controller */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXTIMINGS 150

//#define DEBUG

#define DHT11 11
#define DHT22 22
#define AM2302 22

int readDHT(int type, int pin);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (!bcm2835_init())
        return 1;

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("usage: %s [11|22|2302] GPIOpin#\n", argv[0]);
    printf("example: %s 2302 4 - Read from an AM2302 connected to GPIO #4\n", argv[0]);
    return 2;
  }
  int type = 0;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "11") == 0) type = DHT11;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "22") == 0) type = DHT22;
  if (strcmp(argv[1], "2302") == 0) type = AM2302;
  if (type == 0) {
    printf("Select 11, 22, 2302 as type!\n");
    return 3;
  }

  int dhtpin = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (dhtpin <= 0) {
    printf("Please select a valid GPIO pin #\n");
    return 3;
  }


  printf("Using pin #%d\n", dhtpin);
while(1==1){
  readDHT(type, dhtpin);
sleep(1);

}
  return 0;

} // main


int bits[250], data[100];
int bitidx = 0;

int readDHT(int type, int pin) {
  int counter = 0;
  int laststate = HIGH;
  int j=0;

  // Set GPIO pin to output
  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_OUTP);

  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, HIGH);
  usleep(500000);  // 500 ms
  bcm2835_gpio_write(pin, LOW);
  usleep(20000);

  bcm2835_gpio_fsel(pin, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_INPT);

  data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;

  // wait for pin to drop?
  while (bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin) == 1) {
    usleep(1);
  }

  // read data!
  for (int i=0; i< MAXTIMINGS; i++) {
    counter = 0;
    while ( bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin) == laststate) {
    counter++;
    //nanosleep(1);     // overclocking might change this?
        if (counter == 1000)
      break;
    }
    laststate = bcm2835_gpio_lev(pin);
    if (counter == 1000) break;
    bits[bitidx++] = counter;

    if ((i>3) && (i%2 == 0)) {
      // shove each bit into the storage bytes
      data[j/8] <<= 1;
      if (counter > 200)
        data[j/8] |= 1;
      j++;
    }
  }


#ifdef DEBUG
  for (int i=3; i<bitidx; i+=2) {
    printf("bit %d: %d\n", i-3, bits[i]);
    printf("bit %d: %d (%d)\n", i-2, bits[i+1], bits[i+1] > 200);
  }
#endif

  printf("Data (%d): 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x\n", j, data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

  if ((j >= 39) &&
      (data[4] == ((data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF)) ) {
     // yay!
     if (type == DHT11)
    printf("Temp = %d *Ce, Hum = %d \%\n", data[2], data[0]);
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if(f == NULL){
    printf("nepavyko atidaryt");
    }   
    const char *text = "write this to file";
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", data[2]);
    fclose(f);
    sleep(1);

     if (type == DHT22) {
    float f, h;
    h = data[0] * 256 + data[1];
    h /= 10;

    f = (data[2] & 0x7F)* 256 + data[3];
        f /= 10.0;
        if (data[2] & 0x80)  f *= -1;
    printf("Temp =  %.1f *C, Hum = %.1f \%\n", f, h);
    }
    return 1;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message or just goes plain silent dead?

Comment: +1 for `if(f == NULL)`, -1 for then calling `fprintf()` and `fclose()` regardless ;)

Answer (score 2):

Might not be the only issue, but with every call to `ReadDHT` you keep incrementing `bitidx` here:

```
bits[bitidx++] = counter;
```

But you never reset or decrement it (except for initialization in global scope). So at some point `bitidx` will be out of bounds for `bits` causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: If asker has between 250/10=25 250/9~=30 readings per call in `// read data!` loop, then it might connect with this answer, due to `int bits[250]` overflowing.

Comment: great, it works. to reassign  bitidx to 0 after function performed. Thank you